# How to convert values into percentage in r software

Tags: r

So this is the question.

1. Suppose you track your commute times for two weeks (10 days) and you find the following times in minutes 
   `17 16  20  24  22  15  21  15  17  22`
2. Suppose that the ‘24’ was a mistake, and it should have been 18. Write a code that fixes this, i.e. changing ‘24’ to ‘18’. Then compute for the new mean and standard deviation of the commute times.
3. Write a code which counts the number of instances that the commute time is at least 20 minutes. Then convert this into a percentage.

This is my solution for `Q3` when I ran this code. I want to ask anybody if my solution is correct?

```
commute <- c(17,16,20,24,22,15,21,15,17,22)
commute[commute==24] <- 18
n <- length(commute)
sum((commute>=20)/n)
#[1] **0.4**
```

Comment: looks okay. You might prefer `100* mean(commute>=20)` which will make accounting for any missing variables a bit easier

Comment: Thanks for helpful reply :)

Answer (score 0):

to complete the answer of the user20650, you could use a string formatted command to correctly display the outcome as a percentage as requested:

```
sprintf("%0.2f%%",100* mean(commute>=20))

[1] "40.00%"
```